# Why do people look different in a photo and in a mirror?

Tags: reflection, camera

Edit:

Why do people look different in a photo and in a mirror? What is more accurate of the two?

P.S. I've edited this question and I suppose it is no longer opinion based.

Comment: It's due to a special optical effect that is taking place in the mirrors, see http://www.kb5.cz/wp-content/uploads/2013/03/pouzivani-zrcadla-pri-cviceni-2.jpg

Comment: One should definitely ask, how do you tell if something/someone looks good or bad? But anyway, I guess one answer would be that for seeing we use two eyes(lenses), while for photo shooting we usually use only one lens(eye).

Comment: @LubošMotl So where I can read more about it? Any links you could give me? Because I tried looking it up on Google but I got nothing.

Comment: I was mostly joking, but I was also trying to point out that one has more freedom to fool himself when he looks at himself. The 2D/3D difference may make an impact, and so can the fact that one is moving in the mirror – the cuteness of one's motion may make many people more attractive. Mirrors sometimes have too little lightning - which is better for less physically perfect kinds of skin, and so on. But none of these things may be fully quantified up to the moment when you define what you really mean by beauty which is why 3 people have voted this question to be opinion-based.

Comment: Do you care (re "accuracy") that   a mirror is apparently Left-Right reversed and a camera is not?  One significant difference is that a camera lens "collapses" the depth of hte image while a mirror, having no focus power, does not.

Comment: I've edited the question. I suppose it no longer stands 'opinion based'.

Comment: In a mirror or direct observation of the subject what you see is a composition of two different images received by each eye, allowing for depth perception recreated in the brain. A camera has only one eye, which cannot store this information, leaving depth information largely to shadows--the difference between a pro and amateur photograph where realism is concerned, is subject lighting--not pixels.otherwise the most realistic way would be to use cameras with two eyes, also known as 3d cameras.

Comment: I'm voting to leave closed. As it stands ([v3](http://physics.stackexchange.com/revisions/98705/3)) it reads like you're asking about the inversion properties of the mirror, and it no longer reflects (heh) the original intent of the post.

Answer (score 2):

Actually the resolution of our eye is much more than the resolution of a typical camera. You may have notice that the photo of the same person looks better if the camera is of good quality.The another reason may me the 2D effect made by the camera while our eye can look through the mirror with different angles and can focus various parts of our body perfectly.